# Can I use multiple quantile regression to estimate the probability a dependant variable is above / below a certain value?

Tags: probability, distributions, density-function, quantile-regression, catboost

Let's say I have a dataset of characteristics of newly launched products in a retail environment, and the dependant variable `Y` is total $ sales in the first year of launch.

If I train a quantile regression model on this data for every quantile from 0.01 to 0.99, and plug in data from a new unseen product, would this give me a probability distribution that I could use to answer the below questions?

**What is the probability that, given the characteristics of this new product, the sales will exceed $1,000?**

**What is the probability that, given the characteristics of this new product, the sales will be between $500  and $1000?**

I have started toying with the models just today (using Catboost in python) and they give me a result similar to a probability distribution, but can it be used to calculate the area under the curve of the probability distribution to answer those questions?

I have seen some comments / articles that hint towards using quantile regression for this, but nothing concrete nor demonstrated.

For example, I want to use quantile regression results to do something like this ( examples from google):

[image]

[image]